# Chrome input[type=submit] zoom bug

Tags: google-chrome, button, zooming

So when I zoom on an unstyled button in Chrome (23.0.1271.64) the button text starts to overflow from the button. Is this a bug? Present in all/earlier versions of Chrome? Any easy/quick workarounds?
See here for an example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, Chrome 23.0.1271.95 on OSX 10.7.5

All `<input type="submit" />` and `<button />` look creepy. Text is way outside of element.
All looks fine, when I hit "Zoom-In" twice.

My temporary solution is to use

```
input[type="submit"], button { -webkit-appearance: square-button }
```

Now the button looks squared, but at least the text is within.